# IPTABLES Routing traffic from 192.168.1.1 port 21516 to 192.168.2.3 port 80

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding, nat

I am using Debian/Linux Bullseye (version 11)

What I am trying to accomplish is setting up a TabloTV to portfoward through a Linux firewall using IPTABLES. my linux firewall has two ethernet cards (eth0 actual `enp0s25`) and `eth1` (inside for example) and two separate networks that MASQ and FORWARD traffic.

- `eth0` runs 192.168.1.0/24  (or `enp0s25` in my specific case))
- MASQ b/w and ports all forward
- `eth1` runs 192.168.2.0/24

However, what I want to be able to do is setup a particular computer inside of the firewall to do the following:

- (reroute traffic directed to port 80 on 192.168.2.3 from firewall IP 192.168.1.1 port 21516)
  192.168.2.3:80 to external port number 21516
- (reroute traffic directed to port 8887 on 192.168.2.3 from firewall IP 192.168.1.1 port 21517)
  192.168.2.3:8887 to external port number 21517

It just happens that my firewall external IP is 192.168.1.1, but my inside firewall IP is 192.168.2.1, then the inside computer I am trying to reroute port traffic to is 192.168.2.3.

I have tried the following:

- these lines existed previously as part of the MASQ

  ```shell
  sudo iptables -A FORWARD -d 192.168.2.0/24 -j ACCEPT 
  sudo iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.2.0/24 -j ACCEPT
  ```
- I then added the following lines:

  ```shell
  sudo iptables -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.2.0/24 -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE #this is allow traffic to run on my VPN
  sudo iptables -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.2.0/24 -o enp0s25 -j MASQUERADE #this is allow traffic to run between eth0 and eth1
  sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21516 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.3:80 
  sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21517 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.3:8887
  sudo iptables -A POSTROUTING -d 192.168.2.3/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.1:21516 
  sudo iptables -A POSTROUTING -d 192.168.2.3/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8887 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.1:21517
  ```

Still did not work for me, does anyone have any ideas?